# finding documents where an array in a subdocument has duplicates or is of certain sized

Tags: mongodb

I have the following set of documents:

```
[

    {
        "_id":1,
        "a":2,
        "b":{
            "q":[1,2,3],
            "c":[{"d":1,"e":2,"f":3},{"d":1,"e":2,"f":3},{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5}] 
            }
        },
    {
        "_id":2,
        "a":4,
        "b":{
                "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5}],
                "qq":5
            }
        },

    {
        "_id":3,
        "b":{
            "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5}],
            "ff":5
            }
        },

    {
        "_id":4,
        "b":{
            "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":1,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":3,"f":5}],
            "fre":5,
            "qaacs":[]
            }
        },

    {
        "_id":5,
        "b":{
            "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":1,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":3,"f":5}],
            "fre":5,
            "qaacs":[]
            }
        }


]
```

My goal is to find the documents where the array `"c"` contains either n duplicate elements or m total elements.

For the sake of this example let's let n=2 and m=3.

In this case, the following should be the result

```
[

    {
        "_id":1,
        "a":2,
        "b":{
            "q":[1,2,3],
            "c":[{"d":1,"e":2,"f":3},{"d":1,"e":2,"f":3},{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5}] 
            }
        },
    {
        "_id":2,
        "a":4,
        "b":{
                "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5}],
                "qq":5
            }
        },

    {
        "_id":4,
        "b":{
            "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":1,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":3,"f":5}],
            "fre":5,
            "qaacs":[]
            }
        },

    {
        "_id":5,
        "b":{
            "c":[{"d":2,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":1,"e":4,"f":5},{"d":2,"e":3,"f":5}],
            "fre":5,
            "qaacs":[]
            }
        }
]
```

Finding arrays that have a total of m elements can be obtained with this query
`coll.aggregate([{"$match":{"b":{"$exists":True},"b.c":{"$size":m}}}])` but I don't know how to get the count of duplicates.

My first thought was to use $group on "c" and get counts that way but found that that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator. When used with just an array, it will return unique values from the array.

**Approach:** To calculate `n` duplicates of an array, first, we will calculate the actual size of the array and the size of the unique elements of the array. Now, we will calculate the difference between these two numbers, if it's greater than equal to `n-1`, this means, the array has `n` duplicates (in this case it's `1`, as `n=2`). Finally, using `$or` operator, we will get the required results.

**Query:**

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $subtract: [
                  {
                    $size: "$b.c"
                  },
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $setIntersection: "$b.c"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              1 // Replace this with n-1
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$b.c"
              },
              3 // Replace this with m
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```